# How to decode a base64 encode

Tags: python, pycharm, base64, decode, encode

```
import base64

a = "aGVsbG8"
d = a.encode()

print(d)

z = base64.b64decode(d)
```

It is showing error I already know that this encode's decode is hello but I was trying to get a encoded text of base 64 to decode in a new file but I was unsuccessful. Can anyone solve my problem?

MY PROBLEM IN EASY WORDS :)

its encoded version of hello from base64... I am trying if I get a text suppose from my friend that is encoded from base 64 then can I decode it from base64 only, in my pc?

Answer
Thanks @Olvin

we just need to add "="
in
a = "aGVsbG8"
so it will be a = "aGVsbG8="

and it worked !!!

Comment: `aGVsbG8` is not a valid base64, `aGVsbG8=` is.

Comment: no bro its encoded version of hello from base64 I am trying if I get a text suppose from my friend that is encoded from base 64 then can i decode it from base64 only in my pc  ?

Comment: There's [padding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-3.2) in base64 standard which you missed in encoded string. You can make a "hotfix" by adding padding before decoding `d + b"=" * (-len(d) % 4)`

Comment: Hmm I dont know what padding is ... I am a beginner :) can you tell what more I need to add in my code

Comment: I already told you twice. Encoded `"hello"` is `"aGVsbG8="`, you can encode it and see `base64.b64encode(b"hello")`

Comment: ok wait let me try